# Nested for each loops?

Tags: java, loops, nested

```
        for ( Route r : timetable.keySet())
        {
            for (Station s: r?)   //compile error here.
        }
```

Hi all, basically I'm trying to write a method that adds stations to a combobox from
a timetable. The timetable is essentially a hashmap that returns a Route, List(of type service),
and a route is definined by a string representing the name of the route, and

```
// a list of stations visited on this route 
private ArrayList<Station> stations;
```

Basically I need to access the stations in the route so I'm using a foreach loop to get each route in the timetable and then trying to get all the stations in that route, but
I'm not sure how I would do the second nested loop, as in which list should I be referring 
to as I am getting a compile error if I refer the route.

I cannot modify the Route class, as that has been provided and I need to work around that but it does have this method to return the stations

```
   public Station getStop(int i) {
    if (i < 1 || i > stations.size()) {
        throw new NoSuchStopException("No " + i + "th stop on route" + this);
    }
    return stations.get(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: That condition changes everything. Could you provide the full `Route` class? There should be some other helpful methods.

Comment: Is there a method to get the number of stops?

Comment: Ahhh figured it out! Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to modify the class `Route` and add a *getter* method that returns the `ArrayList` (because it's `private`):

```
public class Route {
    // ...

    public List<Station> getStations()
    {
        return stations;
    }
}
```

Then you can use that method in the `for` loop:

```
for (Route r : timetable.keySet()) {
    for (Station s : r.getStations()) {
        // ...
    }   
}
```

**Edit:** As @DavidWallace mentioned, if you don't want someone to modify the `ArrayList` through the getter method, you can *return* an `unmodifiableList`:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(stations);
```

Comment: You should really put an `unmodifiableList` around the returned value, so that someone can't use the getter to modify the `Route`.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit, but that cast in your edit isn't going to work.

Comment: I have now.  You are editing faster than I can comment.  Thank you for removing the broken cast.

Comment: Well it actually happened because I was returning `ArrayList` instead of `List`.

Comment: Yes, I know.  Good that you've fixed that too.

Comment: I actually can't modify the Route class as it has been provided to me so I need to work around that..

Comment: How is this answer accepted if it modifies the Route class - which the OP said was not permitted?

Comment: @Jason The OP only added that requirement after there were three answers here.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a solution as follows but it doesn't use nested for-each loops since it requires catching the exception to know when there are no more stations for that route (this solution does not require any changes to the Route class):

```
for ( Route r : timetable.keySet())
{
    int stationIndex = 1;
    try {
        do {
            Station station = route.getStop(stationIndex++);
            // todo - put the station in the combo box
        } while(true);
    } catch(NoSuchStopException nsse) {
        // we have reached the index where there wasn't a stop, so move to the next route
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is useful if there is no `getNumberOfStops` method.  The OP has not yet indicated whether there is such a method or not.

Comment: True. We can only base our answers on the information we're given.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as

```
for ( Route r : timetable.keySet()) {
    for (Station s: r.getStations()) {

        // ...

    }
}
```

provided the `Route` class has a method like

```
public List<Station> getStations() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(stations);
}
```

Note the use of `unmodifiableList`.  This prevents someone from writing code that calls `getStations` and then modifies the result.  Basically, it should be impossible to use a "getter" method to modify a class; hence using the various "unmodifiable" wrapper methods in the `Collections` class is best practice for a getter that returns a collection.

**Edit**

Dealing with the new requirement of not being able to change `Route`, and assuming that there is a method `getNumberOfStops` as well as the `getStop` of the question, you could write

```
for (Route r : timetable.keySet()) {
    for (int stopNumber = 1; stopNumber <= r.getNumberOfStops(); stopNumber++) {
        Station s = r.getStop(stopNumber);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for-each` loop iterate collection or array type and `Route` object `r` is not iterable type that is why it raised **compiler error**.

```
for ( Route r : timetable.keySet()){
     for (Station s: r.getStations()){ // Get the station List from route object
       ...
     }   
}
```

Note: assumed there must be getter method of `stations` in `Route` class.

Comment: There isn't a method of getting stations in that way, but I have added addition code from the route class

Comment: yes that is required, that is how you can get `stations` list

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of for each loop

```
for(XXX a : YYY)    
YYY --- > should be any class that implements iterable  
and XXX objects should be in YYY
```